# Load macros from dotm

Tags: vba, ms-word

The scenario:
When word starts, it connects via vba to a Service, which returns a list of paths. Each of These paths points to a .dotm file. These files contain information about various controls (inside the ribbon, for example a butto which adds a specific footer).

What I want: I need a possibility to load several .dotm files, but without copying or moving them to a specific location.

Basically that's it. I've searched wide and far and I have the fear, that this Approach is actually not possible, and that I have to copy all dotm files inside the startup-folder and let word do the rest

Is there any way how I can load several dotm files into a single word-file, so that the ribbon gets extended depending on the dotm's

Best regards, please and thanks :)

Comment: So what you're asking is for a variable number of buttons to be added to a ribbon based on a variable number of macros in a number of files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to load multiple templates to a single Word file. Only one template can be attached to a document.

It is possible to load multiple templates as *add-ins* in the Word environment. These will be available then to *all* documents opened in the Word application. Use the `Addins-Add` method to add a template to the list in Document/Document Template, the "Global templates and add-ins" list. (This is the equivalent of the "Add" button in the dialog box.)

```
Dim bInstalled as Boolean
Dim Path as String
Dim fileName as String

'Populate the variables, then...
Application.Addins.Add Filename:=Path & fileName, Install:=bInstalled
```

Set `bInstalled` to false if you want the template in the list, but not loaded (Ribbon isn't displayed, for example); set it to true to also load it. Once a template is in the list, whether loaded or unloaded, it will generally remain in the list unless Word is reset in some manner. The code for managing template add-ins would be more efficient if it first checks whether an Add-in is already in the list before adding it again.

Templates that are in the list can be loaded/unloaded using the `Addins.Installed` property. If the tools in a template should be available only to certain documents then they can be loaded/unloaded dynamically by using **events**, such as `DocumentChange`.

The code to load the add-ins and manage them (events) should probably be in a central template in Word's Startup folder or in the template attached directly to the document.

Comment: Both answers provided a solid solution, but I love when I get a lot of background-information so I can fully understand the solution provided. Thumbs up!

Answer (score 2):

From word documentation:

> This example attaches the template "Letter.dot" to the active document.

```
ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate = "C:\Templates\Letter.dot"
```

You can use this to attach all your templates to the document.

See also the `Templates` collection.

> you can add a template to the Templates collection by using the Add method with the Addins collection to load a global template

```
Sub AddTemplate()
    ' For this example to work correctly, verify that the
    ' path is correct and the file exists.

    AddIns.Add FileName:="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office" _
        & "\Templates\Letters & Faxes\MyFax.dot", Install:=True
End Sub
```